# Не срабатывает addEventListener после удаления и вставки элемента

Tags: jquery, события, javascript

Всем привет. Я что-то уже совсем затупил. В jquery c помощью метода on можно повесить событие на удаленный и заново вставленный элемент (без перезагрузки страницы). А как это можно сделать на чистом js? Вот наброски сделал - http://jsfiddle.net/PLcBq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [делегирование](http://jsfiddle.net/zyCZ4/1/). Походу, обработчик вешается на dom-элемент. Когда вы удаляете старый и вставляете новый, пускай и такой же, это два разных элемента (как объекты в js). Да, так и есть, потому что [это](http://jsfiddle.net/5JPLh/1/) тоже работает.

Comment: спасибо, все понял)